# Django: Handling form data after a redirect

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I have a Django app with two views (actually more but I'm simplifying). The first view shows a page with details regarding an object and has a form which can be submitted. The second view is called buy the POST request on submitting the form and then redirects back to the first view:

views.py:

```
def main_view(request):
    context = {}
    # other view code here

    context['form'] = Form()

    return render(request, 'mypage.html', context)


def form_view(request):
    form_data = Form(request.POST)

    if form_data.is_valid():
        # process form here

    else:
        # add an informative message
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Error message here")

        return redirect('url_of_main_view')
```

The issue I have here is that I want to pass the form data back to the main view, both to prevent the need to fill in the whole form again, and to allow the validation errors to be displayed.

I would normally do this by simply processing the form within one single view, such as:

```
def view(request):
    context = {}

    # other view code here

    context['form'] = Form()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_data = Form(request.POST)

        if form_data.is_valid():
            # process form data

        else:
            # handle messages
            context['form'] = form_data

    return render(request, 'mypage.html', context)
```

However, this (in my case at least) would result in a large view as I have a number of different forms that can be submitted from this page. I also like to redirect after a form post to avoid the data being re-submitted if the user refreshes the page.

My questions:

1. Is this (the first example) indeed a sensible way of structuring the code for handling forms? Is the second example a more sensible way of doing this, or is there a better idea? Perhaps I should perform form validation within the main view then call a separate method to process the form data?
2. If I were to use the first example, with a separate view to handle a form post, what is the best way to go about handling instances in which the form fails validation and should be passed back to the main view? Should I be using sessions for this, or is there a more efficient/cleaner way of doing this?

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: You can use class based views to handle get and post method in single class.

Comment: If the forms are not big, you could simply pass validation errors back as query parameters (e.g. `redirect('/mainview?name=invalid%20name')`). Another thing which comes to mind is to simply render the template of the main page from second view, instead of doing a redirect, e.g. (`render(request, 'mypage.html', context_with_form_errors)`)

Comment: @vivekpradhan I will take a look at class based views in more detail; I had looked at some simple guides on the subject but they only dealt with one form and a simple view, I also couldn't see how they would handle redirects any differently from standard views. I'll take a better look, thanks!

Comment: @CrowbarKZ Some of the forms are unfortunately fairly large, too large for GET parameters I reckon, or at least too large to warrant this method. The main view and page is fairly complex, hence the need to either redirect to the view or simply have everything run from it. Cheers for the advice though!